# Homotopy type of surface of revolution of a finite graph (Hatcher exercise 0.22)

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Let $X$ be a finite graph lying in a half-plane $P\subset \Bbb R^3$ and intersecting the edge of $P$ in a subset of the vertices of $X$. Describe the homotopy type of the 'surface of revolution' obtained by rotating $X$ about the edge line of $P$.

I already understood that for given graph $X$, we by deformation retract the edges, we may assume all the vertices of $X$ are on the edge of $P$. Hence the possible cross-section of the surface of revolution is loop in each vertices and edges between distinct vertices. Here's where I'm stuck. I thought the resulting homotopy type of the surface is wedge sum of some known spaces like $S^1$, $S^2$ or $T^2$. But I can't see the homotopy further. Could you give any hint or answer?

And using the fact that for space $X$, the surface of revolution is just $S^1\times X$, I thought the cross-section of the surface of revolution could be just wedge sums of $S^1$ by contracting edges connecting two distinct vertices. But this is simply not true considering the case when there are only two distinct vertices on the edge of $P$ and only one edge connecting them (The resulting surface of revolution is $S^2$ but if we contract that edge then it's just a point). Why doesn't work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Homotopy type of surface of revolution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/371152/homotopy-type-of-surface-of-revolution)

Comment: @leslietownes No. I think the solution is not correct. The point is we rotate $X$ about the edge line of $P$. Furthermore, he assumed the graph $X$ is a disjoint union of wedge sums of $S^1$ which is true in terms of graph itself but not available in our situation (and this is also in my question..).

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. It may prevent others from offering similar suggestions. I'll think about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Contracting the spanning tree of $X$, we may assume $X = \bigvee_{i=1}^n S^1$ (Here, we assume $X$ is connected for simplicity). Let $\tilde{X}$ be a surface of revolution of $X$ w.r.t. $\{*\}$ where $\{*\}$ is the wedged point of $S^1$'s. Then the resulting space is a wedge sum of $S^2$ with two points identified which is homotopy equivalent to $S^1\vee S^2$. Hence, the resulting space is homotopy equivalent to $\bigvee_{i=1}^n S^1\vee\bigvee_{i=1}^n S^2$.

Edit: The above solution has some problems so rather than choosing a spanning tree of $X$, we first contract edges of $X$ so that the vertices contained in the interior of $P$ all contracted to vertices lie on the edge of $P$. This can be done on $\tilde{X}$ simultaneously and this process does not change the homotopy type. Now the half side of the cross section of $\tilde{X}$ looks like the below picture. The surface of revolution of this is homotopy equivalent to a finite number of of $S^2$, connected by $1$-cells, with two points identified. See the below picture where the red points indicate the identified points. Each two points identified sphere $S^2/\sim$ is homotopy equivalent to $S^1\vee S^2$. Hence, $\tilde{X}$ is homotopy equivalent to finite number of wedge sum of $S^1$'s and $S^2$'s.

[image: .]
[image: .]

Comment: Contracting the spanning tree without fixing the vertices on the edge of P is not going to induce a continuous homotopy of the rotated graph.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Yes the argument I wrote is quite sloopy. Deformation retract the edges of $X$ relative to the vertices on $P$ so that all the vertices of $X$ lies on the edge of $P$. Then contract the vertices on $P$ to a point which is possible since I assumed $X$ is connected.

Comment: But you can't do that while leaving the vertices on the edge fixed. Just imagine what would happen to the surface of revolution once a vertex pulled away from the edge. It would tear apart.

Comment: Just think about a simple example of an edge in the interior of $P$ connecting two vertices at the edge of $P$. The solid of revolution is a sphere, but your argument would say it was homotopy equivalent to a point.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Yes I spotted that problem. I should say that after I contract edges of $X$ so all the vertices of $X$ lies on the edge of $P$, I contract 1-cells that connects consecutive vertices of $X$. Then the resulting space is homotopy equivalent to $\bigvee_{i=1}^n S^1\vee \bigvee_{i=1}^n S^2\vee\bigvee_{i=1}^k S^2$ for some $n,k\in\Bbb Z$.

Comment: You have to give a much more careful account of what you are doing. If you contract edges connecting vertices of $X$ that lie on $\partial P$, that is happening inside the revolved graph. I think you want to say that when you contract one of these edges, it splits off a copy of $S^2$, but a) that is not in your original answer, and b) it was far from clear to me from your comment. It would be much clearer if you described what you were doing with respect to the revolved space. Right now you do operations on the graphs without clearly stating what the effect on the revolved graph is.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Thank you for pointing it out. I edited the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I was working on this problem today and am posting my full solution since the currently accepted answer is incomplete.

For such a graph $X$, let $R(X)$ be the corresponding `surface of revolution'. Notice that $R(X)$ has a natural CW structure: the 0-cells are the vertices of $X$; the 1-cells are the edges of $X$ and circles at the vertices of $X$ that do not lie in the edge of $P$; each 2-cell is attached to an edge of $X$ and (if the vertices are not in the edge of $P$) the circles at the vertices incident to the edge. We can extend this construction to any finite graph $\Gamma$ with a designated subset $V_P$ of the vertices of $\Gamma$. Define a CW complex $R(\Gamma, V_P)$ constructed as above, with $V_P$ playing the role of the vertices on the edge of $P$. This allows us to work with $R(\Gamma, V_P)$ just as a CW complex and ignore the ambient space $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Let $\Gamma$ be a finite graph, and let $V_P$ be a subset of its vertices. Denote the multiset of edges of $\Gamma$ as $E$ and the set of vertices as $V$. We will write an edge $e \in E$ as $[a,b] = [b,a]$ where $a$ and $b$ are the vertices incident to $e$. With this notation, $E$ is a multiset to allow for multi-edges. The homotopy type of $R(\Gamma, V_P)$ is the disjoint union of the homotopy types of its connected components, so we will assume that $\Gamma$, and hence $R(\Gamma, V_P)$, is connected.

Suppose that $[v_1,v_2] \in E$ with $v_1,v_2 \in V \setminus V_P$ and $v_1 \neq v_2$. Let $C$ be the subcomplex of $R(\Gamma, V_P)$ consisting of the 0-cells $v_1,v_2$; the 1-cells $[v_1,v_2]$ and the circles at $v_1$ and $v_2$; and the 2-cell attached to the 1-cells. Notice that $C$ is homeomorphic to a cylinder and deformation retracts to the circle at $v_1$. Let $\Gamma'$ be the graph with vertices $V \setminus \{v_2\}$ and edges
$$
  \{[a,b] \in E : a \neq v_2 \text{ and } b \neq v_2\} \cup \{[v_1,b] : [v_2,b] \in E \setminus \{[v_1,v_2]\}\},
 $$
where the set-minus $E \setminus \{e\}$ is understood to only remove one instance of $e$. Then by problem 0.27 below, $R(\Gamma, V_P)$ is homotopy equivalent to $R(\Gamma', V_P)$.

Suppose that $[v_1,v_2] \in E$ with $v_1 \in V_P$ and $v_2 \in V \setminus V_P$. Let $V$ be the subcomplex of $R(\Gamma, V_P)$ consisting of the 0-cells $v_1,v_2$; the 1-cell $[v_1,v_2]$ and the circle at $v_2$; and the 2-cell attached to the 1-cells. Notice that $C$ is homeomorphic to a closed disk, so is contractible to the point $v_1$. So with $\Gamma'$ defined as above, $R(\Gamma, V_P)$ is homotopy equivalent to $R(\Gamma', V_P)$ by Proposition 0.17.

So if $V_P$ is empty, it suffices to consider the case where $\Gamma$ has only one vertex (which is not in $V_P$). And if $V_P$ is nonempty, it suffices to consider the case where all of the vertices of $\Gamma$ are in $V_P$.

Case 1: $V_P$ is empty and $\Gamma$ has a single vertex. Consider a torus $T$ as the product space $S^1 \times S^1$. For a disjoint union $\bigsqcup T_i$ of finitely many tori, let $(z,w)_i$ denote the point $(z,w) \in T_i$. Then for $k \geq 0$, let $\mathbb{T}_k$ be the quotient space $(S^1 \sqcup T_1 \sqcup \cdots \sqcup T_k)/\sim$, where the relation $\sim$ is generated by $(z,0)_i \sim z$ for all $z \in S^1$ and $1 \leq i \leq k$. Then $R(\Gamma, V_P)$ is homotopy equivalent to $\mathbb{T}_k$, where $k$ is the number of edges in $\Gamma$, and $\mathbb{T}_k$ (hence also $R(\Gamma, V_P)$) is homotopy equivaent to a 'stack of $k$ donuts'.

Case 2: $V_P$ is nonempty and all of the vertices of $\Gamma$ are in $V_P$.

Suppose that $[v_1,v_2] \in E$ with $v_1 \neq v_2$. Let $A$ be the subcomplex of $R(\Gamma, V_P)$ with 0-cells $v_1$ and $v_2$, a 1-cell $[v_1,v_2]$, and the 2-cell attached to the 1-cell (so $A$ is just a sphere). By collapsing the 1-cell in $A$, we see that $R(\Gamma, V_P)$ is homotopy equivalent to $R(\Gamma', V_P \setminus \{v_2\})$ with an extra 2-cell attached to $v_1$, where $\Gamma'$ is defined as above. Repeating this construction a finite number of times, we see that $R(\Gamma, V_P)$ is homotopy equivalent to the wedge sum of a finite number of $S^2$'s and $R(\tilde{\Gamma}, V_P)$, where $\tilde{\Gamma}$ contains only one vertex $v$ and $V_P = \{v\}$.

So now suppose that $\Gamma$ contains only one vertex $v$ and $V_P = \{v\}$. If $\Gamma$ has no edges, then $R(\Gamma, \{v\})$ is just a single point. Otherwise, consider an edge $[v,v] \in E$. Then the subcomplex $A$ of $R(\Gamma, V_P)$ at $[v,v]$ (with 0-cell $v$, 1-cell $[v,v]$, and 2-cell attached to $[v,v]$) is a sphere with two points identified. By Proposition 0.17, we can replace $A$ with a complex with 0-cells $v'$ and $v$ (where $v$ is the same as before, but $v'$ is a new 0-cell), two 1-cells connecting $v$ and $v'$, and a 2-cell attached to just one of the 1-cells (creating a sphere with an additional 1-cell connecting two points; the resulting space is homotopy equivalent to $R(\Gamma, V_P)$ by Proposition 0.17 by contracting the 1-cell that is *not* contained in the closure of the 2-cell). Then we can contract the 1-cell contained in the closure of the 2-cell, effectively replacing $A$ with the wedge sum $S^1 \vee S^2$ at $v$. Repeating this process for each edge in $\Gamma$, we see that $R(\Gamma, V_P)$ is homotopy equivalent to a finite wedge sum of $S^1$'s and $S^2$'s.

To summarize, supposing that $X$ is connected:

- If the intersection of $X$ with the edge of $P$ is empty, then the surface of revolution has the homotopy type of either a circle or a finite 'stack of donuts'.
- If the intersection of $X$ with the edge of $P$ is nonempty, then the surface of revolution has the homotopy type of either a point or a finite wedge sum of $S^1$'s and $S^2$'s.

---

For completeness, I am including the statements of Proposition 0.17 and problem 0.27 (which is an extension of Proposition 0.17).

**Proposition 0.17.** If the pair $(X,A)$ satisfies the homotopy extension property and $A$ is contractible, then the quotient map $q : X \to X/A$ is a homotopy equivalence.

**Problem 0.27.** Given a pair $(X,A)$ and a map $f : A \to B$, define $X /f$ to be the quotient space of $X$ obtained by identifying points in $A$ having the same image in $B$. Show that the quotient map $X \to X/f$ is a homotopy equivalence if $f$ is a surjective homotopy equivalence and $(X,A)$ has the homotopy extension property.